# C# Mongo query for count with $maxTimeMS

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-4.5

I am trying to implement the $maxTimeMS while I am trying to get the count for my filter from C# MongoDB. I couldn't figure out to do that.

My C# code :

```
var doc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonQuery);           
var query = new QueryDocument(doc);
long Count = base.Collection.Count(query);
```

My Mongo Shell Command which I am trying to actually execute:

```
db.MyCollection.find({ "$query": {"Age" : 101}, "$maxTimeMS": 100 } )
```

But in my C# Mongo I am using Count Method to get the count and not using find method and my need is how to set the $maxTimeMS in the C# query when executing to get count?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is [`CountOptions`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_CountOptions.htm) which is basically the same as [`FindOptions`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions.htm) so you can do:

```
var options = new CountOptions
        {
            MaxTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };

long Count = base.Collection.Count(query,options);
```

Or even just:

```
var options = new FindOptions
        {
            MaxTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };

long Count = base.Collection.Find(query,options).Count();
```

Comment: Thank you @Blakes!! Is there any difference in execution for the above 2 statements ? performance etc...

Comment: @Prabhakaran Nope. The "chained" execution will return a an object that is modified by `.Count()` before execution. They are basically the same. I am just demonstrating that the "abstract" type for "options" is also the same.

Comment: Thank you @Blakes. One more question regarding the cursor execution for Find or FindAs command, If I am setting the MaxTime for cursor and when iterator runs to get the data , at what time the timeout exception will happen? is it during the iteration or when I am execute the Find or FindAs command to get the cursor?

Comment: @Prabhakaran misread that at first. The "timeout" is for "query duration" and not while "fetching results" from a cursor. Cursor timeouts are a different thing.

Comment: Thank you and noted. Can we set timeout for cursor explicitly or from .Net can we terminate the long running cursor(not inactive cursor).

Comment: @Prabhakaran If you have another question then post another question. This was answered two day ago.